# Friendly urls for MODx in php dev server

Tags: php, modx

I try to run the copy of my modx-based website locally via `php -S localhost:8000`. All works fine except that friendly urls like `/mypage` returns content of index page (it's default modx behavior for 404 pages). I tried to use router (`php -S localhost:8000 router.php`) but it doesn't work.

```
<?php
    /*  Friendly Urls
        ================================================
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
        RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
        ================================================ */

    $root=__dir__;

    $uri=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
    $q=trim($uri,'/');   

    if (file_exists("$root/$q") && is_file("$root/$q")) {
        return false; // serve the requested resource as-is.
        exit;
    }

    $_GET['q']=$q;
    require_once 'index.php';
?>
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, I converted the original code to this one, which seems to be correct:

```
<?php
/*  Friendly Urls
    ================================================
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
    ================================================ */

$root = __DIR__;

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];
$path = ltrim($uri, '/');

if (file_exists("$root/$path")) {
    return false;  // serve the requested resource as-is.
    exit;
}

$q = urldecode($path);

$_GET['q'] = $q;
$_REQUEST['q'] = $q;

require_once 'index.php';
```